# Need query to get list of values for a particular attribute in whole xml document

Tags: marklogic

Please let me know the query to fetch list of values for a particular attribute in whole xml document. Example: I have a huge xml file and want to fetch all the values assigned to an '@xyz' attribute. I can loop through and get the values but want to know is there any simple way/query(javascript) by which I can achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1):

1) Lexicon (modify tokenizer if more than one word)
It you add a lexicon to the attribute, then you would be able to retrieve a unique list of all words. By tuning the tokenizer, you would be able to get back values even with spaces, etc. Then use [cts:element-attribite-word-match()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-attribute-word-match) to get the values back

2) Range Index
Use a range index and retrieve the values with [cts:values()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:values)

Some Further Reading (in addition to the inline links above):
[Admin guide to range indexes and Lexicons](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index)
[Search Guide for browsing with Lexicons](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/lexicon)